# Run a pyarmor obfuscated code through a python file that is passed as a string

Tags: python, python-3.7, obfuscation, pyarmor

I have obfuscated the code using pyarmor and return it through a python function, where I can run the obfuscated code when the python file is run.

```
# the obfuscated code returned from function to 'msg'

msg = testExtract.getobfcode()

# value returned

# from pytransform import pyarmor_runtime
# pyarmor_runtime()
# __pyarmor__(__name__, __file__, b'\x50\x59\x41...x27', 1) #value is truncated
```

I tried using the **os.system** to run this in a cmd

```
os.system('cmd/c "msg"')
```

also tried to run using **exec** as the code is passed as a string

```
def execute():
    code = msg
    exec(code)


execute()
```

both ways didn't work. how do I run this obfuscated code through a py file?